# How do I change the search provider for IE10 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

When I click on "Find more search providers", I get taken to Microsoft's site but it just says "No results were found.". Where can I get the Google Search provider plugin thing manually?

[image]

Comment: I want to set Google as the default search engine for IE10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [Google Search Provider](http://www.iegallery.com/en-US/Addons/Details/813) manually, just follow the steps after click on "Add to Internet Explorer".